# jQuery that targets Mobile + CSS Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, header

I'm currently using the following to remove my header from certain pages that contain .iframe-nav

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 if($(".iframe-nav").length > 0) // If .iframe-nav exists
    $("#main-header").hide(); // Hide #main-header
});
```

This works great. My problem is that I have other pages that contain ".iframe1" which are not affected by that script, and because of that appear incorrectly on mobile devices. I need both separate CSS classes for reasons I won't go into now.

Is there a way to remove #main-header from pages that contain  **.iframe1** as well as from my mobile site **@mobile only screen and (max-width: 767px)**  ?

I tried the following to test removing  #main-header from all mobile pages (as a test), but was unsuccessful. I still have a lot to learn...
Did not work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 767px)').matches) {
   $("#main-header").hide(); // Hide #main-header
}
```

Thanks very much advance.

Comment: How are you testing this? are you using a desktop browser and just resizing the window?  Also http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia is only IE10+ are you testing in IE9 perhaps?

Comment: I'm using Safari on iPhone to test these mobile cahnges. And usually Chrome or Safari for desktop testing. (osx)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to put you logic into `$(window).on("resize"` block as follows:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(newWindowWidth < 767) //check for width
    {
       $("#main-header").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey @vijayP , your solution got me part-way there. But I'm having two problems:

1- I still need to additionally target the  .iframe1  class in the script, so that only pages with that class are prevented from displaying a navigation on mobile devices. 

2- The script is successfully removing  #main-header from the mobile site, but only after scrolling has been activated. This might be related to my wordpress premium theme's responsive breakpoints.  If you thought you could help with this, I could PM you my CSS etc. 

Any additional help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!